# How to write a given integer as sum of other integers?

Tags: number-theory, analysis, elementary-number-theory, summation

Given are a set $S$ of random positive integers (not necassarily distinct) and another positive integer $x$. I look for an algorithm to find all possibilities to write $x$ as a sum of integers in $S$, but each integer in $S$ can only be used once.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Is there a time efficiency constraint? The simple "try all possibilities" is always an option...

Comment: Should be as fast as possible :)

Comment: You appear to be speaking of the [Subset Sum Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

Comment: @lulu thus proves that... there is no time efficient way (np complex problem). Simple "try it all" might be the best way